# Snowflake "Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded" error when loading data from Parquet

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to load data from S3 into Snowflake.  My files are in Parquet format, and were created by a spark job.  There are 199 parquet files in my folder in S3, each with about 5500 records.  Each parquet file is snappy compressed and is about 485 kb.

I have successfully created a storage integration and staged my data.  However, when I read my data, I get the following message:

```
Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded, actual size of parsed column is 19970365
```

I believe I have followed the [General File Sizing Recommendations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html#general-file-sizing-recommendations) but I have not been able to figure out a solution to this issue, or even a clear description of this error message.

Here is the basics of my SQL query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY STAGE my_test_stage
            FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = PARQUET)
            STORAGE_INTEGRATION = MY_STORAGE_INTEGRATION
            URL = 's3://my-bucket/my-folder';

SELECT $1 FROM @my_test_stage(PATTERN => '.*\\.parquet')
```

I seem to be able to read each parquet file individually by changing the URL parameter in the CREATE STAGE query to the full path of the parquet file.  I really don't want to have to iterate through each file to load them.

Comment: Is it possible you have a bad file somewhere in there?  Maybe try the full query with a SKIP_FILE or CONTINUE option for your ON_ERROR parameter and see if there is either a bad file or a bad record in a file that is causing you issues.

Comment: Try basing your inference on ONE file from the stage https://stackoverflow.com/a/77625082/769405

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be issue with one or more records from your file, try to run copy command with "ON_ERROR" option, to debug whether all the records has similar problem or only few.

Comment: As this answer and @mike-walton mentioned, I was able to narrow down this issue by using the COPY command (not SELECT) and setting VALIDATION_MODE = RETURN_ERRORS and ON_ERROR = CONTINUE.

Answer (score 2):

The VARIANT data type imposes a 16 MB (compressed) size limit on individual rows.

The resultset is actually a display as a virtual column, so the 16MB limit also applied

Docs Reference:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html#semi-structured-data-size-limitations