# Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded, actual size of parsed column is 18840934 in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to generate JSON object using object_construct and array_agg  function by joining the parent table with 6 child tables in Snowflake. while executing the query got the below error.
Please suggest.

Max LOB size (16777216) exceeded, actual size of parsed column is 18840934

Comment: You can't create a field value greater then 16Mb. You will need to think up a different approach to what you are trying to achieve i.e. splitting the json into multiple columns/rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum length of a field in a query projection cannot exceed 16MB and is a hard limit that cannot be increased.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html?_ga=2.86776536.1713968334.1654050526-74044833.1649643991#semi-structured-data-size-limitations

You could try NewLine delimited JSON.

https://medium.com/@kandros/newline-delimited-json-is-awesome-8f6259ed4b4b

You could also try the solutions mentioned in the below link

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Max-LOB-size-exceeded

Answer (score 0):

INFER_SCHEMA scans your stage location and if its big, in our case multiple TB it can take a long time and with a lot of data associated with columns it will bomb out with that LOB error.

If you know that your files all have the same structure, types etc, what you can do is base your inference on the first file in the stage. Just do a select on the stage files metadata and limit by 1 to get 1 file.

```
SET FIRST_FILENAME_IN_STAGE = 
(SELECT SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME, '/', -1) 
FROM @MY_STAGE(file_format => aws_parquet) limit 1);

SET PATH_OF_FIRST_FILE_NAME = '@MY_STAGE' || $FIRST_FILENAME_IN_STAGE;


CREATE OR REPLACE  EXTERNAL TABLE MY_TABLE_EXTERNAL
  USING TEMPLATE (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*))
    FROM TABLE(
      INFER_SCHEMA(
        LOCATION=>$PATH_OF_FIRST_FILE_NAME,
        FILE_FORMAT=>'aws_parquet'
      )
    )
  )
  LOCATION=@MY_STAGE
  FILE_FORMAT=aws_parquet
  AUTO_REFRESH=false;
```